# Convert an existing Blazor WebAssembly (hosted) App into a PWA Problems

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, blazor, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

I recently created a Blazor WebAssembly (hosted) app. Now I needed a notification service. I converted my existing project strictly according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

When I start debugging in VS2019, there is no PWA functionality in the App and when I deploy it in Azure App Services, the functionality appears. The Data is provided by the databse but when I click a button, nothing happens at all. No SignalR processing, no database processing.

I suspected that in local debugging the service-worker.js doesn't work well and therefore there is no PWA in sight. When I deploy it the PWA works because of the switch to the service-worker.published.js.

Why does PWA not work in debugging?

If it is working, why is the application not working anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research I found that there is an on-going issue for PWA with VisualStudio-2019 in [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/edge-developer/issues/252).

But you can use VisualStudio-2017 for debugging the PWA application by following the this [link](https://blog.ailon.org/pwa-on-windows-tools-to-develop-and-debug-windows-specific-features-782d29dbb28a).